# Why can't I change elements in this array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

In Unity I create five lists of bools and put them in a jagged array as shown below (in my gamecontrol script). I initialize the 5 List in the inspector in unity, so no initialization is needed in code. During runtime I can access these lists from the inspector.

```
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameControl control;
        public List<bool>[] ascensionUpgrades;
        public List<bool> ascensionUpgrades_0;
        public List<bool> ascensionUpgrades_1;
        public List<bool> ascensionUpgrades_2;
        public List<bool> ascensionUpgrades_3;
        public List<bool> ascensionUpgrades_4;

    void Awake () {

            if (control == null) { 

                DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
                control = this;

            } else if (control != this) {

                Destroy (gameObject);

            }

    ascensionUpgrades = new List<bool>[] {ascensionUpgrades_0, ascensionUpgrades_1, ascensionUpgrades_2, ascensionUpgrades_3, ascensionUpgrades_4};
    }
```

}
At a certain point in the game I do load a new scene, gamecontrol persists due to the dontdestroyonload command. Afterwards when I want to change the values of the bools from another scrupt it looks like this:

```
GameControl.control.ascensionUpgrades[0][0] = true;
Debug.Log ("Upgrade changed_A?: " + GameControl.control.ascensionUpgrades[0][0]);
Debug.Log ("Upgrade changed_B?: " + GameControl.control.ascensionUpgrades_0[0]);
```

The value of ascensionUpgrades_0[0] is not set to true. But when I print the value of ascensionUpgrades[0][0] that is indeed true. I expect them to both be true, as I've made the jagged array to better organize and access the bool lists. Debug Log does not show any errors. Can you help me find out where the problem is?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I suspect that you're reinitializing `ascensionUpgrades_0` to refer to a different list at some point.

Comment: Please post code that shows your problem because what you have posted throws an exception.

Comment: not reproducible

Comment: I have added some more details and this should be reproduceable. I suspect it has to do with perhaps loading a scene.

Comment: Your code still throws an exception because `ascensionUpgrades[0]` is null. If you're not getting that you must have some code you're not showing us. The problem is in code you're not showing us.

Comment: I've tried to explain that I am initializing the lists in the inspector which is default unity feature. I am not sure how else to explain since there is no code that initializes the lists and I don't want to make code up. if I should not ask unity questions here that is understandable, but still weird since I had the option to specify this is a unity3d related question and did so.

Comment: It still seems like there is code not shown in the question that is making `ascensionUpgrades[0]` and `ascensionUpgrades_0` refer to different lists.

Comment: @DourHighArch Asker has already explained that the lists are defined and populated in the inspector (and `Awake` would adequately overwrite any configuration of `ascensionUpgrades` in the inspector). I don't think a screenshot of the inspector is necessary but it does seem like there is missing code.

Comment: @DorukOkbay Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ascensionUpgrades is only updated once, on Awake. When you load a new scene, Awake won't be called again on that script, so it will have the same values as before.

Possible solution would be to make a method that updates ascensionUpgrades when you load a new scene. For example

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
//change other ascensionUpgrades arrays here
GameControl.control.UpdateAscensionUpgrades();
```

Then in GameControl, you add

```
public UpdateAscensionUpgrades(){
    ascensionUpgrades = new List<bool>[] {ascensionUpgrades_0, ascensionUpgrades_1, ascensionUpgrades_2, ascensionUpgrades_3, ascensionUpgrades_4};
}
```